# SFDX Jenkins Authorization

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkinsfile

How to deploy Source Format Git Branch into non-scratch org or full copy sandbox or production without using Devhub authorization in Jenkins?

The command I am trying to use:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath force-app --targetusername yourSandboxOrProdUsername
```

Comment: Ans : After trail and error found this the best command to authenticate the org in jenkins sfdx auth:jwt:grant -u {UserName} -f {JWT KEY file} -i {ClientId} -r https://test.salesforce.com -a {alias}

Answer (score 2):

There are some steps to be followed here. It cannot be answer in this scope, but on high level.

First you need to Store `sf auth url` for target environment.

Only after that you need to configure your `yml` or `xml` file to read this auth url and set it dynamically using `sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f <file containing sfdx auth url>`

After that when you run `sfdx force:source:deploy -x -u Dynmamicusernamefromproperties` or `sfdx force:source:deploy -p -u Dynmamicusernamefromproperties` it will deploy your code to targetted environment.

You can easily google the setup and follow the steps. Tons of example out there.

Comment: I tried sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f <file containing sfdx auth url> in local and it is working fine.But when i tried to do it in Jenkins it is failing with this Error.```ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store:  Invalid sfdx auth url. Must be in the format `force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<loginUrl>`. The instanceUrl must not have the protocol set.```